# How to fit a cumulative time series?

Tags: reference-request, statistical-inference, linear-regression, regression-analysis

Assume we have a time series of $N$ different points $(t_i,y_i)$, for $i \in \{1,..N\}$. The number $N$ is "small" (let's say $3<N<10$, just to give an idea), so you may want to make good use of all the information in the data.

Define now a **cumulative time series**, namely

$$(t_1,y_1),(t_2,y_1+y_2),\ldots ,(t_N,y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_N).$$

I would like to estimate the slope of this "cumulated" series of data (and the uncertainty on this slope), which can be naively estimated as

$$\dfrac{y_2+\cdots +y_N}{t_N-t_1}
\qquad \text{or}\qquad
\dfrac{y_1+\cdots +y_{N-1}}{t_N-t_1}
$$

However, apart from not knowing which of the two options is a better estimator of the slope (they both look legit), we also have no idea of the associated uncertainty.
One option is to make a linear regression on the points of the cumulative. However, in this way, the information provided by $y_1$ (or $y_N$) is lost!

Which is the best (or standard) way to perform a linear regression in this case (or to estimate the slope of the cumulated data set)? Moreover: is it even possible to use the [usual least mean squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) method? (I guess not, since the cumulated data do not have the [homoscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity_and_heteroscedasticity) property).

**Answer to the question:** This question is closely related to [How to infer the average speed of a frog?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3688072/532409). After some research, I concluded that a **satisfying answer can be found in** [Fitting a Straight Line to Certain Types of Cumulative Data (1957)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2281706), [Parameter Estimation with Cumulative Errors (1974)](https://doi.org/10.2307/1267496) and the methods described in [Statistical estimates of the pulsar glitch activity (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.01539).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really should be a comment, but don't have enough reputation. Try [Holt's method (double exponential smoothing)](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/2).

The formulation looks like it'll fit your problem domain. In the absence of a trend, even exponential smoothing will work pretty well. A lot of statistical packages have built-in methods for this.

Comment: Thank you, your idea was insightful but in the end I found a satisfying answer in the two papers that I have linked at the end of the question.