# How to infer the average speed of a frog?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, random-variables, statistical-inference, stationary-processes

Let's model the motion of a jumping frog as a [continuous-time stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_stochastic_process). The model for this process depends on a parameter $V_\infty$, the "true" average velocity of the frog.
We want to infer $V_\infty$ from a finite set of observations.

**The process:** The frog jumps a distance $J_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$ at times $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$, for $i=1,...,N$. The average velocity of the frog over long time intervals converges to $V_\infty$.
The jumps are instantaneous and all in the same direction. The underlying stochastic process is [stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Strict-sense_stationarity), at least in a [wide-sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity).

[image]

**Possible estimator of $V_\infty$:** An [estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator) of $V_\infty$ could be the ratio between the  empirical *mean  of the jumps* over the empirical *mean of the "waiting time"* between consecutive jumps:
$$
v_N =  \left( \frac{t_N-t_1}{N-1} \right)^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N J_i \right) 
$$
Assuming to know the details of the process, is there a way to tell how much $v_N$ is an accurate estimate of $V_\infty$? Are there better (possibly unbiased) estimators for $V_\infty$?

**Question:** given the observations $( t_i \, , \, J_i )_{i=1..N}$, how to theoretically infer $V_\infty$?
I am OK with partial answers: I hope that someone can help me **find the correct mathematical framework** for this kind of question. Is there any known kind of stochastic process with *real and positive amplitudes that occur at random times*? It seems like a [generalization of the Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) (maybe this process is a [subordinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subordinator_(mathematics))?). Any good reference?

**It seems not easy:** We have data only for a "single and partial history" of this stochastic frog, not different possible realizations of its motion (we do not have an ensemble of frogs all with the same $V_\infty$). Is it possible to quantify how much the estimate of $V_\infty$ given by $v_N$ is reliable? Partial answers pointing out the difficulties or which hypotheses could improve the feasibility of the task are well appreciated.

**Related practical question and partial answer:** this problem may be regarded as the "theoretical counterpart" of [How to fit a cumulative time series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2654497/532409): to practically estimate $V_\infty$, we could fit the cumulative time series constructed from the observed data $(t_i, J_i)$. After some research, I concluded that a **satisfying practical answer can be found in** [Fitting a Straight Line to Certain Types of Cumulative Data (1957)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2281706), [Parameter Estimation with Cumulative Errors (1974)](https://doi.org/10.2307/1267496) and the methods described in [Statistical estimates of the pulsar glitch activity (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.01539).

Comment: Are all random variables in your problem ($\delta t_i$s and $J_i$s) independent? Also, do they have finite moments?

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. Yes, they have finite moments (otherwise the problem is probably hopeless) but they are correlated (after a big jump the frog has to rest a bit more..). For i.i.d. $J_i$ and i.i.d $\delta t_i$ it seems that $V_\infty = E[J]/E[\delta t]$, where $\delta t$ is the "resting time" between jumps.

Comment: One way it is hopeless is that you have a finite span of observations.  Say you have watched for $10^6$ seconds and the average speed has been $1$ unit/sec but on average every $10^7$ seconds the frog makes a jump of $10^9$ units.  Your estimate is off by a factor $100$.

Comment: Nice point, is there a mathematical way to make this consideration more formal? Some formula involving $T$, the length of the observation time, and the stationary probability $p(\delta t , J)$ that you may infer from a "$T \rightarrow \infty $" observation?